# "this.label is undefined" on refresh - jQuery Mobile checkboxradio 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm getting this error and I don't understand what is wrong: **TypeError: this.label is undefined**

I try to dynamicly add checkboxes (ajax) and their style, but if I call the refresh method I get this error.

Inside **success** from Ajax call:

```
var foo = '<div data-role="fieldcontain">'
        +'<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">'
        +'    <legend>Choose as many snacks as youd like:</legend>'
        +'  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" class="custom" />'
        +'  <label for="checkbox-1a">Cheetos</label>'

        +'  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a" class="custom" />'
        +'  <label for="checkbox-2a">Doritos</label>'

        +'  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3a" id="checkbox-3a" class="custom" />'
        +'  <label for="checkbox-3a">Fritos</label>'

        +'  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4a" id="checkbox-4a" class="custom" />'
        +'  <label for="checkbox-4a">Sun Chips</label>'
        +'</fieldset>'
        +'</div>';

        $("#panel-wo-item").html(foo);          
        $("#panel-wo-item").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");
```

And html:

```
<div id="panel-wo-item">
    <!-- checkboxes -->
</div>
```

If I remove .checkboxradio("refresh"); it works, but looks "unstyled" and ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [checkboxradio](http://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/) widget is supposed to be applied to a single `<input>` element. You're applying it to a container, which is probably the cause of your problem.

You also do not have to instantiate these widgets explicitly, jQuery Mobile can do that for you with [a single method call](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/):

```
$("#panel-wo-item").html(foo).enhanceWithin();
```

Comment: .enhanceWithin(); Did it! Works now